# Loading images via JFileChooser

Tags: java, image, swing, panel, jfilechooser

3 Classes - GUI, ImageLoader and Wizard

GUI is the main frame whereas Wizard is just a popup that changes settings and imageloader is image handler

What I want is to load image from wizard to Jlabel on my main GUI but I have no idea where to start and never had experience with loading images onto GUI. Searching for answer on here didn't really help, it just create more confusion for me. I would appreciate if you also can add explanations as well.

GUI -

```
public class GUI extends JPanel{
   //variables
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("All-in-one Application");
   JMenuBar menuBar;
   JMenu file, edit, help, about;
   JMenuItem settings, startWizard, exit, save, load, readme;
   JLabel imgLabel;
   private Wizard wiz;
   

   public void topMenuBar(){
      
   //creating the menubar
   menuBar = new JMenuBar(); 
   //Menu
    file = new JMenu("File");
    edit = new JMenu("Edit");
    help = new JMenu("Help");
    about = new JMenu("About");
    
    //MenuItems 
    startWizard = new JMenuItem("Start Wizard");
     //listener for wizard
     Wizard wiz = new Wizard();
   //  GUIListener gListener = new GUIListener();
     startWizard.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            wiz.startWizardd();
         }
     });
    
    settings = new JMenuItem("Settings");
    readme = new JMenuItem("Read Me");
    exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    save = new JMenuItem("Save");
    load = new JMenuItem("Load");
    

    //jbutton
   // test = new JButton("Test");

    //adding MenuItems to the Menu
   
    /**file**/
    file.add(startWizard);
    file.add(new JSeparator());
    file.add(save);
    file.add(load);
    file.add(new JSeparator());
    file.add(exit);
    //end file 

    //edit
    edit.add(settings);
    
    //help
    help.add(readme);
    //about
    
   //Adding Menu to the menu bar 
   menuBar.add(file);
   menuBar.add(edit);
   menuBar.add(help);
   menuBar.add(about);
   
 
   //exit action listener 
   exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         System.exit(0);
      }
   });
  }
  
  public void mainPanel(){
  
    FlowLayout main = new FlowLayout();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(main);  
    
    //jlabel
    imgLabel = new JLabel("img");
    
    
    mainPanel.add(imgLabel);
    
    frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  
  }
   
   
    //intiate GUI
   public void intGUI(){
     
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setLocation(300,0);
      frame.setSize(1400,1000);
      topMenuBar();
      mainPanel();
      frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    
      frame.setVisible(true);
   } 
}
```

Wizard:

```
public class Wizard extends JPanel{

   //variables 
    private ImageLoader imgload = new ImageLoader(this);
    private JButton applyButton, nextButton, backButton, cancelButton, openMapButton;
    JDialog wizDialog;
    JFrame wizFrame;
    JLabel siteNameLabel, siteMapLabel, AisleNumLabel, laneNumLabel, label; 
    JTextField siteNameField, aisleNumField, laneNumField;
    private JTextField mapURLField = new JTextField(20);
    JFileChooser chooser;
    private File file; 
    String fileName;
    BufferedImage img;   // private JPanel addInfoPanel, controlPanel;
     
    public void startWizardd(){
      System.out.println("Starting Wizard....");
       wizardGUI();
    }
    
    public void wizardCmpt()
    {
      
      //setting the panel up with gridlayout settings
      FlowLayout map = new FlowLayout();
      JPanel mapPanel = new JPanel();
      mapPanel.setLayout(map);
      
      FlowLayout grid = new FlowLayout();
      JPanel addInfoPanel = new JPanel();
      addInfoPanel.setLayout(grid);
      
      FlowLayout controls = new FlowLayout();
      JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
      controlPanel.setLayout(controls);
      
      
      //buttons
      JButton openMapButton = new JButton("Load Map");
      openMapButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            imgload.fileChooser();
         }
     });
     
      
      JButton applyButton = new JButton("Apply");
      applyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              
          }
      });
      JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
      JButton backButton = new JButton("Back");
      JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
      cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){            
            wizFrame.setVisible(false);
            wizFrame.dispose(); 
         }
      });  
      
      //jlabels
      JLabel siteNameLabel = new JLabel("Site Name :");
      JLabel siteMapLabel = new JLabel("Site Map :");
      JLabel AisleNumLabel = new JLabel("Number of Aisles :");
      JLabel laneNumLabel = new JLabel("Number of Lanes :");
      
      //jtextfield
      JTextField siteNameField = new JTextField(5);
      JTextField aisleNumField = new JTextField(5);
      JTextField laneNumField = new JTextField(5);
      
      
      //adding to GUI  
      addInfoPanel.add(siteNameLabel);
      addInfoPanel.add(siteNameField);
      
      addInfoPanel.add(AisleNumLabel);
      addInfoPanel.add(aisleNumField);
      
      addInfoPanel.add(laneNumLabel);
      addInfoPanel.add(laneNumField);
      
     mapPanel.add(siteMapLabel);   
     mapPanel.add(mapURLField);   
     mapPanel.add(openMapButton);

      
      controlPanel.add(applyButton);
     // controlPanel.add(nextButton);
    //  controlPanel.add(backButton);
      controlPanel.add(cancelButton);
      
      wizFrame.add(addInfoPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      wizFrame.add(mapPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      wizFrame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);  
      
    }
    
 
    public void setMapUrlField(String text){
      mapURLField.setText(text);
    }
    
    public File getFile(){
      return file;
    }
          
    private void wizardGUI(){
            System.out.println("it's loading");
            wizFrame = new JFrame("Wizard Operation");
            wizFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            wizFrame.setSize(600,600);
            wizardCmpt();
            wizFrame.pack();
            wizFrame.setVisible(true);          }  }
```

Image Loader:

```
public class ImageLoader{

   private JLabel label; 
   JFileChooser chooser;
   File file; 
   private BufferedImage img;
   private Wizard wiz; 
   
   public ImageLoader(Wizard wiz){
      this.wiz = wiz;
   }

   public File fileChooser(){
        File file = null;
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileFilter imageFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image files ", ImageIO.getReaderFileSuffixes());
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(imageFilter);
        int retValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(wiz);
        if(retValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
         file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
         wiz.setMapUrlField(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }else{
         wiz.setMapUrlField("");
      }
      return file;
    }
}
```

Comment: *it just create more confusion for me.* - well we have no idea why you are confused. The steps are basic: 1) get a file name 2) read the file 3) create an ImageIcon, 4) create a JLabel using the ImageIcon 5) add the label to the frame. So restart your program and solve one step at a time. That is first start with "hard coding" the file name and implement all the other steps. Only once that process is working to you attempt to use the file chooser to prompt for the file name. The point is you need to learn to walk before you run.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) sections.

Comment: Start by reading the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on `How to Use Icons` which is a complete example and `How to Use File Choosers`. Combine the code from both examples to implement your solution. 90% of the code posted is NOT related to your actual question which is why you need to simplify the code.